# How to implement timer callback independent of the system time in C++ using boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost, timer, systemtime

I need to create a timer which will call my function periodically (e.g. every 50ms).
BUT the problem is I will need to change the system time while the timer is running.
I would like to do this using boost so that the code is portable. Otherwise I am running it on Linux machine.

Things I have tried:

- Tried using a while loop and thread::sleep. Calculated the sleep time using steady_clock.
- Also tried using deadline_timer

Both of these stop working when the system time is adjusted.

Question:
Is there any way (using boost preferably) to create a callback timer which is independent of the system time? (Bonus karma for sample code)

Comment: ?? If you sleep() for a 50ms interval, changing the system time should not affect it.

Comment: it does. I changed my system time forward (past the 50ms) and the timer stopped

Comment: `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug under linux. You need to use a sleep method, that uses the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (`boost::this_thread::sleep` uses `CLOCK_REALTIME`). `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` with the boost chrono library should do this, because it uses the monotonic clock.

```
while (true) {
    // Call your function here.
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Alternatively you could use `boost::this_thread::sleep_until`. With that function you could use a custom clock.

But the underlying `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` could be influenced by `adjtime()`. Therefore you could use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` as a linux only alternative.

One more possibility: If you are able to use C++11 you could use `std::chrono::steady_clock` to get a strict monotonic clock.

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
while (true) {
    std::cout << (start - std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).count() << std::endl;
}
```

The output here will not change, if the system clock gets adjusted. But do not use this with `boost::this_thread`. Use it with `std::this_thread::sleep_for` to get proper results.

The last possibility is just to use `usleep` or `nanosleep`.

But be aware, that you will not be able to interrupt the sleep with the last two options (STL and OS specific calls).

Comment: Tried and still doesn't work. When I move the system time backwards it stops until the time catches up.

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW would solve this, but there is as far as I know no implementation of that in boost. In the STL there is the `steady_clock` for that.

Comment: Yes, using CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW I got it to work but not with the steady_clock.

Comment: Which system do you have. On Mint 13.10 with g++ 4.8 it works with the `steady_clock`. The STL standards says, that that clock would never jump.

Comment: Fedora 20, boost 1.54, g++ 4.8.3